# Compiz Expo expo_edge setting not retained after restart

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz

I used the TopRight setting for my expo_edge setting. On each reboot this setting is non-functional even though it is still set in gconf-editor settings. I can reset things by using gconf-editor to remove the setting and then add the setting back. However, the next boot the setting is again non-functional.

I am unsure what is causing the conflict, but moving the edge to BottomRight enables it to remain functional after a reboot. The BottomRight is normally what I use for my initiate_all scale setting so I would like to keep the expo_edge setting in the TopRight if possible.

update: If I do alt+f2 and unity --replace the setting is lost as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used gconf-editor to edit the following settings:

compiz-1 > general > screen0 > options > active_plugins

I changed expo to be the bottom plugin and the setting now is retained after restart or unity --replace